# Sentence Transformers Using BOW?

Tags: nlp, word2vec, bert-language-model, doc2vec, sentence-similarity

I have a collection of terms that appear or are somehow related to web pages (e.g. keywords from the HTML tags). These are not sentences, they are just a collection of keywords, words in a title etc. I am interested in, given such a webpage, to find those most similar. In a case where one has sentences / paragraphs I would think of using a sentence transformer or even like Doc2vec. But in this case I only have the set of words of a page and there is no real context or sentences. Am I correct this precludes me from using sentence transformer / Doc2vec ?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing precludes you from using anything. The relevant test is: does using it work, for your unique data & goals?

`Doc2Vec` and other shallow techniques work fine on things like lists-of-keywords that aren't perfect grammatical sentences: they're generally using the presence or absence of words, without rigorous grammatical understanding, as signals. And that's plenty for many purposes!

Some deeper transformers *might* have more order-dependent reliance on coherent natural-language utterances – but I wouldn't be sure of that until it was tried and shown lacking. It might work! And noone with only the vaguest sketch (from your question) of your data & goals can give you hints better than your own experiments.

Try things – including super-simple things like cosine-similarities on bag-of-words representation, or keyword searches based on some measure of most significant terms – then evaluate the results according to your needs/desired results.

You might start some evaluations via ad-hoc eyeballing – "this seems good, this seems wrong" – but would ideally record judgements of which docs "should" be more-similar than others, in your desired end-system, so that eventually you can run an automatic, quantitative comparison of alternate approaches.